# ScrollViewer and LonglistSelector Scrollbar conflict

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, scroll, windows-phone

In my application i have unknown number of categories, with unknown number of elements. The problem that i am facing is in the UI. 
A Page contains  `ScrollView` wiht items `Button` and `LongListSelector`(with horizontal scrolling).

Basically my layout looks like:

```
<Grid>
 <ScrollViewer>
  <StacPanel>
   <Button/>
   <LongListSelector/>
   ...
  </StacPanel>  
 </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

[image]

So when i try to scroll (horizontal or vertical it doesn't matter) i have to repeat the gesture 3- 5 times for scrolling can begin. And for example when i am scrolling horizontal (one of the LLS), i have to change the focus by click on the button so the vertical scrolling can begin. 
Obviously there is conflict between the scrollbar in LLS and SV, but how can i avoid it?

Any help will be appreciated, also if you have better ideas or alternative - that will be great. Do not hesitate to suggest.

Sorry for my english and bad explanation.

Comment: Do you use this layout for each category? If I uderstood correctly you only need one LongListSelector for your scenario.

Comment: no, i have several for each category

Comment: please show some xaml code with appropriate attribute you specified.
so, someone can suggest you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if anyone will face the same problem again, but what i have done and what seems to work for me is this.

1. I have created a custom control witch replace buttons and longlistselectors in the scrollviewer
2. Then i take a slider [from this project](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2010/10/04/a-better-slider-for-windows-phone-7.aspx) and create custom `RepeatButtons`.

The idea is than my custom control is a slider pointer, maybe this is not the best solution, but what makes me happy is the performers, it's just great.

Answer (score 1):

You should Use the LongListSelector Header and Footer to put your buttons and on your ScrollViewer set VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" to disable the scrollviewer Vertical scrolling on the scrolView and do the reverse on the LongListSelector scrollviewer
If you don't find any other solution, you could use the Manipulation event and RenderTransform to make yourself the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: there is no difference when i put the button in the header, on the contrary it's getting worse, and also some category have more than 50 items

Comment: i am struggling with that for three days

Comment: I'd suggest you to rethink your layout in a way so there is no need to scroll both vertically and horizontally on the same page, and show only a few first\most important items from each category

Comment: If you put the button on the header then you remove the outer SCrollViewer

Comment: @Encarmine this is design specification, the client wants it that way

Answer (score 1):

Although couldn't understand your UI hierarchy thoroughly, however I ran into some similar situation, where I overcome the conflict, by using dynamically built panorama control for horizontal content.

Comment: it gonna work for one but i have unknown number of categories